# Google Calendar Api v3 forbidden response while inserting event

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have an application which sync its entries with Google Calendar. I am using Http Rest calls to insert events using offline authentication for users. Here is the Json that i am trying to push but gives 403 Forbidden error

```
{
  "summary": "4 p.m. - Public Course CMS",
  "start": {
    "date": "2016-03-30"
  },
  "end": {
    "date": "2016-03-30"
  },
  "reminders": {}
}
```

This results in this 403 Forbidden response

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Forbidden"
 }
}
```

I don't know whats wrong with it. Please help. Url is

https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/arcis.golf@gmail.com/events

And i have authorization header containing access token

```
request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer " + accessToken);
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Please post the raw HTTP request including headers.

Comment: i do add Authorization header in c sharp. Please check code